# Receiver using a NE602 oscillator-mixer not working

Tags: receiver, equipment-design, 20m-band

I built a CW receiver using  NE602 for the 20m band. Unfortunately, I do not receive any CW or SSB signals, only some noise and sometimes broadcast stations.

The schematic here shows the circuit that I built. What is wrong in the oscillator and input stages of ic that can not focused on 14 - 14.35 mhz (20m amateur band)

In oscillator section as you see i used two 220pf capacitor that are in series with each other so the total capacitance is equal to 110pf . 
For resonance  at 14 mhz with present inductor (1uH) we need a capacitor value 129pf   using formulae:                    (C=1/39.5 * F^2 * L)        so if the varactor diode can induce about 19pf , the work is done (110+19=129)   the second image show the internal transistor of ne602 chip and relationship between pins 6 and 7 and the other parts of oscillator section
                                     (https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1HLp.jpg)[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  You wrote that you receive only "HF".  Since 20M *is* HF, that makes sense.  Perhaps you can clarify?

Comment: Thank you for adding the details! :-) Perhaps someone here that's smarter (and with more time) than me will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Infact these problems and abnormal behavior of circuits will cause to increase my electronic knowledge and finding good friends like you

Answer (score 2):

In your schematic, there is no way that the IC can get any power because:

1. DC cannot flow through capacitors. I suggest that you look at a [NE602 data sheet](https://www.google.com/search?q=ne602).
2. There is no power being applied to pin 8.

I assume that you are receiving broadcast stations, digital transmissions, etc. Without power to the IC, it's just acting as an AM detector.

Comment: @Farshadmahmoodi Understood. Unless someone else sees something that I didn't, it appears that you might have to show us your entire circuit. Perhaps photos of both sides of your printed circuit board would help.

Answer (score -2):

You have a lot capacitance un serie 200 200 100n 100n AND only 30p un parale.

Make 100n to 100p or less.